# Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<1 , |y|<1$ Prove S is a open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Good morning, i'm stuck with this exercise.
Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<1 , |y|<1$ Prove S is a open set

Definition: $A$ set is open if for all $a∈S$ exists $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)⊂S$

My work:

Suppose $(x,y)\in S$.

Let $r=?$

We need prove $B((x,y),r)\subset S$

Let $(a,b)\in B((x,y),r)$ then $d((a,b),(x,y))<r$

In this step i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you draw a picture of what $S$ looks like? Can you compute a good choice of $r$ for some particular points, e.g. $(0.9, 0.9)$?

Comment: which metric are you using that for sure the key point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you draw a picture. The set $S$ is a square, with side length $2$, whose centre is at the origin. You just need $r$ to be the smallest distance from the point $(x, y)$ to a side of the square: either $x = 1$, $y = 1$, $x = -1$, or $y = -1$. So, your $r$ will be the minimum of four possibilities:

$$r = \min \lbrace 1 - y, y + 1, 1 - x, x + 1 \rbrace.$$

You need to convince youself that these are indeed the right formulas for the distance of $(x, y)$ from the four sides. Or, really, you just need to show this particular $r$ works.

Comment: Is a little complicated to me see that r. Can you explain me why you take that r?

Comment: Each of the expressions in the minimum formula relate to the distance from the point to a side of the square. For example, one side of the square is given by the line $x = 1$. Think about the distance from a point $(x, y)$ to the line $x = 1$: it should be $|x - 1|$. Since the points are to the left of this line (i.e. $x - 1 < 0$), this evaluates to $1 - x$. You can similarly relate the other terms to the other sides. So long as the radius is shorter than all of these distances, the ball shouldn't leave the square.

Comment: Thanks for explain me. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** You can check that $S=(-1,1)\times (-1,1)$. For a hint on this, think about what $\lvert x\rvert<1$ means on the real axis.

Now, take $p\in S$. Let $p=(p_1,p_2)$ for $\lvert p_1\rvert<1$ and $\lvert p_2\rvert<1.$ Take $m=\max(\lvert p_1\rvert, \lvert p_2\rvert)$. Set $r=\frac{1-m}{2}$. Finally, verify that $B_r(p)\subset S$. To see this, fix $q\in B_r(p)$ written as $q=(q_1,q_2)$ and see how large the $\lvert q_1\rvert$ and $\lvert q_2\rvert$ can be. This should show that $S $ is open.